# UIButton different alignment for title and image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uistoryboard, title

Hello I am creating `UIButton` which is displaying image and title at the same time. I want title and image to be both centred, button to be above image. Problem is that because of localisation of string from button, string length is changing, and alignment from `UIStoryboard` combined with edge insets is not working as I want it to work. Can someone help me and point me in the right direction?

Comment: can u some screen shot which type u need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set these two.
 1. set Align controls of UIButton

2. set Image and Text Inset of UIButton

[image: set Align Control of UIButton]

Comment: I did that, but problem is that inset is FIX value, and when you apply localisation (english and german for example) character number in single word is not identical. And inset is always fix value. That is the problem.

Comment: Now you set text inset according to your text by programming.Calculate text height and set 'Text Inset'.

Comment: I managed to do it aligning it from storyboard, and with some coding, calculating string length I set correct insets.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought is that you could build a UIView showing image and text, then attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to it, which would be more flexible than UIButton.

Comment: Problem is that grey appearance of text and image when button is selected is lost when gesture recogniser is attached.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try to set title like this:

```
[someButton setTitle:@"\nsome title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where `\n` is a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust titleEdgeInsets and imageEdgeInsets accordingly

```
[self.facebookButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_icn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[self.facebookButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Invite via Facebook1",nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.facebookButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
self.facebookButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0);
```