# UIButton image on right title in center

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton, insets, imageedgeinsets

I was searching through the post and trying to figure it out by myself but it is hardly working.

I want to use an `UIButton` with image and title.
`UIButton` spans across (almost) whole screen.
The image should be positioned on the right edge of the button.
The title should be centered in the whole button.

How can I do it with insets?

Comment: you need to set `[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f)];` Where
UIEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake (
   CGFloat top,
   CGFloat left,
   CGFloat bottom,
   CGFloat right
);

Comment: Yeah I know about method, my question is, what values should I use?
(I don't want to use magic numbers)

Comment: refer this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340575/uibutton-different-alignment-for-title-and-image/28341513#28341513

Comment: Please share screen shot of expected output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided I have used

```
Control.ContentEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -imageWidth, 0, 0);
Control.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, controlWidth, 0, 0);
```